# Exception: Could not parse query :containsOwn(text)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsoup

hi all
i am using jsoup in a java-ee app to parse html

i want to get the first tag which contains a text,
and when trying to run the following code, i got an exception:

```
org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query :containsOwn(text)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.findElements(Selector.java:143)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.select(Selector.java:90)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.select(Selector.java:68)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(Element.java:162)
```

code is:

```
String html = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\"></style></head><body><div style=\"font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt\">first text<br><div><br></div><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 14pt;\"><br><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 12pt;\"><font size=\"2\" face=\"Tahoma\"><hr size=\"1\"><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">one:</span></b> second text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">two:</span></b> third text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">three:</span></b> fourth text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">five:</span></b> fifth text<br></font><br>";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        String firstText = document.select(":containsOwn(text)").first().text();
        System.out.println(firstText);
```

so any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, your HTML doesn't look well formed, you have extra `div` after `first text`:-

```
<div ...>first text<br><div><br></div>
```

Second, you probably need to use `matchesOwn` because `containsOwn` will search for specific text, based on the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Try this:-

```
String html = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\"></style></head><body><div style=\"font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt\">first text<br><br></div><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 14pt;\"><br><div style=\"font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 12pt;\"><font size=\"2\" face=\"Tahoma\"><hr size=\"1\"><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">one:</span></b> second text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">two:</span></b> third text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">three:</span></b> fourth text<br><b><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">five:</span></b> fifth text<br></font><br>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
String firstText = document.select("div:matchesOwn(\\w+)").first().text();
System.out.println(firstText);
```

... and the printed result is:-

```
first text
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works fine, but what if i want to adjust the above example to make it work to get the first text in general not deciding that it's in a specific tag (meaning, get the first text in a document), will it work like this document.select(":matchesOwn(\\w+)").first().text();

Comment: Yes, `document.select(":matchesOwn(\\w+)").first().text();` works fine too. I just tested it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick feedback, i have one more question though if you can help, is how to get the html content of that first element the matched the regex, not the text ? to get an output something like <div style=\"font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt\">first text<br><br></div>

Comment: Yes.... just do `System.out.println(document.select(":matchesOwn(\\w+)").first());`

Comment: thanks a lot, you are really very helpful, one last question forgive me, is that what if I want to get the inside content of the tag, which maybe a combination of both text & other tags ?